# Use datareader.GetSchemaTable to create SQL Server CE table

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, sql-server-ce, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using an `IDataReader` in .Net to run queries against Oracle and SQL Server databases... Is there any way to use the result of [GetSchemaTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getschematable) to *easily* create a SQL Server CE 4 table? This seems to me like one of those things someone should have invented already, I just can't seem to find it.

I found [this project](http://dbschemareader.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex, which is almost exactly what I need, but not quite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my SQL Compact scripting API, allows you to generate any type of SQL based on a SQL Compaxct schema: http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks! I was able to take a chunk of the codebase to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

To get Schema of a table in databases which do not provide any `GetSchema` kind of functions, we normally run a Select command.

```
"Select top 1 * from mytablename"
```

Fill a DataTable with this command.

This will give you a Single row or may be not if the table is empty,  but will provide the schema of the concerned table.

I had a same problem when i was asked to do so in SQLite and i did as mentioned above.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I have schema information. I have it from SQL Server, and Oracle. I need to use that schema info to generate CREATE TABLE sql statements fitting SQL Server CE 4 syntax. I'm asking if there's a library or NuGet or CodePlex or something out there that already does this... it seems like there should be.